# keras resnet load_model() fails with "ValueError: Shape must be rank 3 but is rank 4..."

Tags: python-3.x, keras, save, load, resnet

I've created a ResNet1D model with keras-resnet 0.2.0 (python3), and have fit my data over many epochs without any issues, but after saving, then simply trying to read the model back in (via load_model), I get a tensor shape mismatch error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1607, in _create_c_op
    c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be rank 3 but is rank 4 for 'padding_conv1_2/Pad' (op: 'Pad') with input shapes: [1,?,30,2], [3,2].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 661, in model_from_json
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 168, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 147, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1107, in from_config
    return cls(inputs=input_tensors, outputs=output_tensors, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_resnet/models/_1d.py", line 184, in __init__
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_resnet/models/_1d.py", line 82, in __init__
    x = keras.layers.ZeroPadding1D(padding=3, name="padding_conv1")(inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 489, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 2151, in call
    return K.temporal_padding(inputs, padding=self.padding[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2759, in temporal_padding
    return tf.pad(x, pattern)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 2840, in pad
    result = gen_array_ops.pad(tensor, paddings, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 6399, in pad
    "Pad", input=input, paddings=paddings, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 794, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3357, in create_op
    attrs, op_def, compute_device)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3426, in _create_op_internal
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1770, in __init__
    control_input_ops)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1610, in _create_c_op
    raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: Shape must be rank 3 but is rank 4 for 'padding_conv1_2/Pad' (op: 'Pad') with input shapes: [1,?,30,2], [3,2].
```

I've pared down the model as much as I could and saved the model alone (21kb, without weights) as JSON, in this [github repository](https://github.com/wt18/keras-resnet-json-load-fail).

I can duplicate the error with the following snippet.  Keras-resnet needs to be installed in python3, and you'll need the [ck.json](https://github.com/wt18/keras-resnet-json-load-fail/blob/master/ck.json) file from the repository.  Below, a custom object dictionary is supplied to model_from_json() because the model contains a custom layer.

```
from keras.models import model_from_json
import keras_resnet
from keras_resnet.models import ResNet1D18

with open('ck.json', 'r') as f:
    model = model_from_json(f.read(), {'ResNet1D18': keras_resnet.models.ResNet1D18})
```

I'm very new at this, so I hope I simply did something silly, but the problem doesn't seem to be shape mismatches in the model itself, because I can create the model, fit data, and save the model with no problems.  **Reading** the saved model back in elicits the error.  From the model summary below, the first ZeroPadding1D layer's input shape is (?, 30, 2) but how does the saved model transform that to (1, ?, 30, 2) as in the error above?

Thanks in advance for any help!

The model summary is:

```
Model: "resnet1d18_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 30, 2)        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
padding_conv1 (ZeroPadding1D)   (None, 36, 2)        0           input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1 (Conv1D)                  (None, 15, 64)       896         padding_conv1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn_conv1 (BatchNormalization)   (None, 15, 64)       256         conv1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_relu (Activation)         (None, 15, 64)       0           bn_conv1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool1 (MaxPooling1D)            (None, 8, 64)        0           conv1_relu[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
padding2a_branch2a (ZeroPadding (None, 10, 64)       0           pool1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a_branch2a (Conv1D)         (None, 8, 64)        12288       padding2a_branch2a[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2a_branch2a (BatchNormalizati (None, 8, 64)        256         res2a_branch2a[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a_branch2a_relu (Activation (None, 8, 64)        0           bn2a_branch2a[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
padding2a_branch2b (ZeroPadding (None, 10, 64)       0           res2a_branch2a_relu[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a_branch2b (Conv1D)         (None, 8, 64)        12288       padding2a_branch2b[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a_branch1 (Conv1D)          (None, 8, 64)        4096        pool1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2a_branch2b (BatchNormalizati (None, 8, 64)        256         res2a_branch2b[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2a_branch1 (BatchNormalizatio (None, 8, 64)        256         res2a_branch1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a (Add)                     (None, 8, 64)        0           bn2a_branch2b[0][0]              
                                                                 bn2a_branch1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a_relu (Activation)         (None, 8, 64)        0           res2a[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool5 (GlobalAveragePooling1D)  (None, 64)           0           res2a_relu[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
fc1000 (Dense)                  (None, 1)            65          pool5[0][0]                      
==================================================================================================
Total params: 30,657
Trainable params: 30,145
Non-trainable params: 512
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line https://github.com/wt18/keras-resnet-json-load-fail/blob/master/ck.json#L11

This makes the `input_shape` to be `(None,  30, 2)` instead of `(30, 2)`.

Try delete this line.

Comment: Thank you, however, I actually want the input shape to be (None, 30, 2) because the first dimension is the batch dimension; i.e., input_shape is actually (batch_size, 30, 2). Also, the ck.json file is simply written with "model.to_json()".  BTW, if I delete the "null" line, then the error becomes: ```ValueError: Shape must be rank 3 but is rank 2 for    'padding_conv1_2/Pad' (op: 'Pad') with input shapes: [30,2], [3,2].```

I don't understand why, if the batch dimension is included, the input shape to the ZeroPadding1D layer is [1, ?, 30, 2], and if deleted, it's just [30, 2].